# Cosmos DB query Error with Code:SC1001 While using Distinct

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to query the cosmos through the documentClientHelper. I have the query which works well in the query explorer but using the same query with parameters, throwing the error at the join .

The error hitting as -

**Error**:

> Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core: Message:
>   {"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":428,"end":432},"code":"SC1001","message":"Syntax
>   error, incorrect syntax near 'join'."}]}

My query as follows:

```
    SELECT 
    c.itemCode,c.itemType,c.name,r    
    FROM Products c join r in c.rates     
    WHERE (ARRAY_CONTAINS(r.branchCodes, 80171, true)) AND (c.itemCode = "0600160")     
    ORDER BY c.name
```

The following query fails at the below section :

```
var queryText = "SELECT 
        c.itemCode,c.itemType,c.name,r    
        FROM Products c join r in c.rates     
        WHERE (ARRAY_CONTAINS(r.branchCodes, 80171, true)) AND (c.itemCode = "0600160")     
        ORDER BY c.name";
var querySpec = new SqlQuerySpec(queryText);

 var query = documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<Product>(collectionUri, querySpec, feedOptions).AsDocumentQuery();
   var response = await DocumentClientHelper.ExecuteWithRetries(async () => await query.ExecuteNextAsync<Product>());
```

Comment: You've shown the query that works, but you haven't shown your code where it *doesn't* work. Pleaes edit your question to show that.

Comment: If you think my answer helps you,could you mark it for answer.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my test, both of the two ways working fine.

***Sample data:***

```
[
    {
        "name": "aa",
        "rates": [
            {
                "branchCodes": [
                    80171,
                    80172,
                    80170
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "aa",
        "rates": [
            {
                "branchCodes": [
                    80170
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "aa",
        "rates": [
            {
                "branchCodes": [
                    80172
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

***query sql in the portal :***

```
SELECT 
    c.itemCode,c.itemType,c.name,r    
    FROM Products c join r in c.rates     
    WHERE (ARRAY_CONTAINS(r.branchCodes, 80171, true)) AND (c.name = "aa")     
    ORDER BY c.name
```

[image]

***SDK code with `SqlQuerySpec`***

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using System;
using System.Linq;


namespace JayGongDocumentDB.module
{
    class QueryWithSqlParam
    {
        private static readonly string endpointUrl = "https://***.documents.azure.com:443/";
        private static readonly string authorizationKey = "***";
        private static readonly string databaseId = "db";
        private static readonly string collectionId = "coll";

        private static DocumentClient client;

        public static async void QueryTest()

        {
            client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), authorizationKey);
            var uri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId);

            String sql = "SELECT c.name,r " +
                            "FROM Products c join r in c.rates "+
            " WHERE(ARRAY_CONTAINS(r.branchCodes, 80171, true)) AND(c.name = \"aa\") " +
            " ORDER BY c.name ";

            IQueryable<Pojo> queryable = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Pojo>(
                                                uri,
                                                new SqlQuerySpec
                                                {
                                                    QueryText = sql
                                                });

            foreach (Pojo p in queryable)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nRead {0}", p);
            }
        }
    }

    class Pojo : Document
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: If you think my answer helps you,could you mark it for answer.Thanks a lot.